# Android App Gets NullPointerException When Trying To Call A Method From Helper Class

Tags: java, android

I have only been developing Android for two weeks now and have done lots of googling into this problem I have but can't seem to get anything to work.

I have a Helper Class which has one method to set up `DatePicker` Limits etc.

```
public class AlarmHelper extends Activity {

    public void setupDatePicker(){
        long maxTime = 52560000;
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        dp.setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis() - 1000);
        dp.setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis() + maxTime);
    }

}
```

I then try to call the `setupDatePicker()` from the `MainActivity` in the `onCreate()` method like so.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    AlarmHelper helper = new AlarmHelper();
    helper.setupDatePicker();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

When I run the app I get a `NullPointerException`. I believe it has something to do the the Context but I haven't got a clue how to implement it within my helper class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does `AlarmHelper` extend `Activity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently you are trying to `findViewById` before setting Activity layout .change your Activity `onCreate` code as :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

       // your code here...
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   //<< set layout for Activity here

    AlarmHelper helper = new AlarmHelper(MainActivity.this);
    helper.setupDatePicker();


}
```

and in your AlarmHelper no need to extends Activity class if it's not an Activity .Change your `AlarmHelper` class as because to access UI elements from other non Activity class you will need to pass activity context :

```
public class AlarmHelper  {

Activity activity;

public AlarmHelper(Activity activity){
  this.activity=activity;
}

    public void setupDatePicker(){
        long maxTime = 52560000;
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)activity.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        dp.setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis() - 1000);
        dp.setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis() + maxTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi There, your solution worked. Thanks very much for the quick response and the clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Move setContentView() before setupDatePicker()

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 AlarmHelper helper = new AlarmHelper();
 helper.setupDatePicker();
```

Anyway, create an activity inside the activity is terrible!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it still crashed when I started the app I'm afraid.